# How to get a cookie jar object from dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, cookies, cookiejar

For default Selenium get_cookies() method returns list of dicts e.g.

```
current_cookies: [{'domain': '.domain.com',
                       'expiry': 1667110148,
                       'httpOnly': False,
                       'name': '_ym_isad',
                       'path': '/',
                       'sameSite': 'None',
                       'secure': True,
                       'value': '2'},
                      {'domain': '.domain.com',
                       'expiry': 1698574147,
                       'httpOnly': False,
                       'name': '_ym_uid',
                       'path': '/',
                       'sameSite': 'None',
                       'secure': True,
                       'value': '1667038148592302065'}]
```

I want it to be a cookiejar object so that I could use methods which cookie jar use e.g.
cookie.expires, cookie.name etc

My current code When I am getting cookies from request.session everything is ok - it automatically creates cookiejar objects but when I use Selenium it creates dicts and I have no idea of how to change this to cookiejar

Code for selenium to obtain cookies

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
s = Service('/Users/almeco/Downloads/projects/research/refs/seo_tools_ref/sdf/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

driver.get('https://my.adcombo.com/login')
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/loginform/form/input[1]').send_keys(
    'email_address')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/loginform/form/input[2]').send_keys(
    'pass')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/loginform/form/button').click()
time.sleep(3)
current_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

The above code returns list of dicts instead of lists of cookie jar objects. My question is how to get cookie jar objects instead of dicts.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html

And then something like:

```
import http.cookiejar as cookielib

def to_cookielib_cookie(selenium_cookie):
    return cookielib.Cookie(
        version=0,
        name=selenium_cookie['name'],
        value=selenium_cookie['value'],
        port='80',
        port_specified=False,
        domain=selenium_cookie['domain'],
        domain_specified=True,
        domain_initial_dot=False,
        path=selenium_cookie['path'],
        path_specified=True,
        secure=selenium_cookie['secure'],
        expires=selenium_cookie['expiry'],
        discard=False,
        comment=None,
        comment_url=None,
        rest=None,
        rfc2109=False
    )


def put_cookies_in_jar(selenium_cookies, cookie_jar):
    for cookie in selenium_cookies:
        cookie_jar.set_cookie(to_cookielib_cookie(cookie))
```

Comment: thanks! One question though: what value does cookie_jar argument need to have? selenium cookies are the cookies I got from get_cookies() selenium method but cookie_jar?

Comment: Not sure found code on https://gist.github.com/xinghe-gao. But i think its something like import http.cookiejar, urllib.request
cookie_jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
put_cookies_in_jar(selenium_cookies, cookie_jar)